# How to run 4000 users in Azure VM

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is to run 4000 users in 1 hour for a product search. I tried to set it up using the GUI and ran with 1000 users. But in my local system, it's not running and my Jmeter is hanging. What I did is, have created an Azure VM configuration as 8 Core processor, 32GB RAM, and it's a windows machine. But this time I checked my baseline with 5 users in GUI mode. Later on, my intention is to increase the load by 50, 100, 500, 1000 and 4000. But When I run with 100 users also in GUI mode Jmeter is hanging. What I did is I ran the script in Non-GUI mode. But with 50 users I was able to run and getting the result. When I increase the load to 100, Java heap memory exception is getting.  Can anyone suggest me how run this scenario is Azure VM. In regular machine, it's not working so only I have gone through Azure VM.

Let me know if anything is needed from my end.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't run your tests in GUI mode, it's only for tests development and debugging. For real load test execution always use [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Increase JVM Heap size, by default JMeter 5.4.1 comes with 1 GB heap allocation which might not be sufficient for your case, i.e. [line #151 of `jmeter.bat` startup script looks like](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L151):

   ```
   set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
   ```

   this `-Xmx1g` stanza tells JVM to not to use more than 1 GB for the heap space, you might want to ramp-up it to i.e. `24g`

   See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more details
4. Even if you manage to run the test with 4000 users on this VM make sure to monitor its resources (CPU, RAM, Network, pagefile usage, etc.) as it might be the case it will be overloaded and will not be able to send the requests fast enough, in this case you will need to add another VM and [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of comments I have to do here

First thigs first, **you should never run your JMeter performance test using the GUI**  as specified [in their documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

> Don't run load test using GUI mode !

GUI mode is for designing and quick testing things. I'd say that even JMeter tells you that when you start it from the CLI

Second, it seems that you're facing vertically scaling limitations (JIC, we say that we're scaling vertically when we put "a bigger machine" to work). When you start getting into a high number of users (such as 4000) scaling vertically starts to show some issues, and while possible you should try to go for an horizontal scaling strategy (JIC, we say that we're scaling horizontally when we put more machines to work in parallel)

Luckily, JMeter supports horizontal scaling out of the box. They call it [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

As a summary, you'll need to perform the following steps:

1. Setup several machines, they don't need to be super big machines. I'd recommend you playing around a little bit with the specs. I'd say to go with a machine that can support 250-500 users
2. Configure these machines to act as worker nodes

   - Make sure to start them in CLI mode!
3. Start your controller node. This can be your own local machine

   - Since you won't be running load, you can start it in GUI mode!
4. Run your tests

   - While they're running, I'd recommend monitoring the worker nodes as well

Start just with one node and, once you have it working, add the rest of nodes

As an extra step, you could configure some scripts (or even better, a CICD pipeline) to rampup dynamically the required number of worker nodes based of the number of users you want. If we maintain the 500 users/machine, you'd need 8 nodes for your 4k users. But potentially you might need to repeat the scenario with 10k or more users